# How can I get Jackson to deserialize XML strings to composite Java object with JAXB annotations containing @XmlAnyElement

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb, jackson-databind

I have the following JAXB annotated classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "payload"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class MyResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected MyPayload payload;

    public MyPayload getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myPayload", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class MyPayload {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected Object any;

    public Object getAny() {
        return any;
    }

    public void setAny(Object value) {
        this.any = value;
    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "mySpecificPayload", propOrder = {
    "field1",
    "field2",
})
public class MySpecificPayload {

    @XmlElement(name = "field-1", required = true)
    protected String field1;
    @XmlElement(name = "field-2")
    protected String field2;

}
```

When I try and deserialize an input of:

```
<response>
  <payload>
    <my-specific-payload>
        <field-1>value1</field-1>
        <field-2>value2</field-2>        
    </my-specific-payload>
  </payload>  
</response>
```

using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
MyResponse value = mapper.readValue(myXmlString, MyResponse.class);
```

I get:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "my-specific-payload" (class
>   com.example.MyPayload), not marked as ignorable (one known property:
>   "any"])

I would like to be able to do:

```
MyResponse value = mapper.readValue(myXmlString, MyResponse.class);
MySpecificPayload msp = (MySpecificPayload) value.getPayload().getAny();
```

Currently using jackson libs with version: 2.9.6 How can I get jackson to achieve this?

Thank you kindly,
Jason

Comment: Something's missing here- do you mean for `MySpecificPayload` to _extend_ `MyPayload`? nothing actually references the specific payload class or type from the response root.

Comment: Thanks @J.Dimeo I can't change the hierarchy of objects as it is but would making MySpecificPayload to extend MyPayload help me here?

Comment: Not sure, but I do see that nothing references MySpecificPayload in any way, so of course Jackson is trying to make it a MyPayload with the any property. Is this auto generating from XSD? you can specify inheritance in the XSD that will translate to an `extends` in the code.

Comment: Said another way, `MyResponse` is a concrete class and `MyPayload` is a concrete class, and `MyResponse` references a `MyPayload`. `MySpecificPayload` doesn't show up in that part of the class tree, so it's "invisible" to Jackson when dealing with `MyResponse`